# JavaFX container in ScrollPane not showing

Tags: java, javafx

I have heard that, to add more controls/JavaFX `Node`s to a `ScrollPane`, one must set the `ScrollPane`'s content to a container, then add all `Node`s to said container. However, when trying this, I only get a small, grey bar without any content. How can I fix this? (Trying to make something larger, but even this MWE doesn't work for me... - Working with OpenJDK OpenJFX 11 on Manjaro, if that helps)

Code:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {
        Label test = new Label();
        test.setText("Testing JavaFX........");
        VBox box = new VBox();
        ScrollPane pane = new ScrollPane(box);
        pane.setPrefSize(300.0, 300.0);
        box.getChildren().add(test);
        Scene main = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setScene(main);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Result:
[image: Small white window with a weird grey bar at the top]

Comment: worksforme (openjfx11 and probably all others on win)

Comment: maybe  your setting somewhere is wrong because it works great for me.I not sure because I am new in javaFx.